# Read/Write a file from/to network folder/share using Python?

Tags: python, network-shares

How to Write/Read a file to/from a network folder/share using python? The application will run under Linux and network folder/share can be a Linux/Windows System.

Also, how to check that network folder/share has enough space before writing a file?

What things should i consider?

Comment: Do you believe that, if you have 400 MiB disk space left and you write 390 MiB of data, you'll always be left with 10 MiB space? Even if you're the sole user of the system, are you sure you're also the sole *writer* to the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount the shares using Samba, check the free space on the share using `df` or `os.statvfs` and read/write to it like any other folder.